# jasper report printing using dot matrix letters sticking each other

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports, dot-matrix

I am using jasper report to print the bill through the dot matrix printer on the continuous 80 column sheet. I am facing the problem the each character was sticking with each other at the time of printing in dot matrix,if i am using laser printer its printed correctly , the problem is only on dot matrix printer.I am using TVS Champion series and Epson LX -310 . Any can help me on this issue please.

Thanks,

Comment: Me too have the same problem, were you able to fix it?